# Video play on mouseover/thumbnail image show on mouse out

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to play a video on mouseover and rewind to beginning and show initial thumbnail image on mouse out.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<video poster="image.jpg" src="video.webm" id="id0" onMouseOver="id0.play()" onMouseOut="id0.pause();currentTime = 0;window.location.reload()" onclick="window.location='video.webm';id0.pause()" loop title="video.webm" ></video>
```

But that just reloads the entire page and not just the thumbnail image.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm answering on a whim here, but maybe replace "window.location" with "this"?

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of more help, I still don't understand why you are using BOM with "window.location.reload()" tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `load()` method like so:

```
function stopReload() {
  vPlayer.pause();
  vPlayer.currentTime = 0;
  vPlayer.load();
}
```

See [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/66ttbv5o/)